# C#/WPF Improving performance of fill update of 1000s of controls simultaneously via datatriggers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So on the model side I have a 100x100 array of Cell objects. The objects have a single property, State, which is a bool. Cell implements INotifyPropertyChanged. I also have a CellCollection object, which holds the 100x100 array and has methods for modifying that array.

On the view side, I have a canvas containing 10,000 Rectangle controls, arranged in a 100x100 grid. Each of the elements of the 100x100 array is set as the DataContext of their corresponding Rectangle in the Canvas. A DataTrigger is defined for Rectangle controls in the XAML that binds on the State property of the Rectangle's DataContext. If the value of State is True, the background of the Rectangle is set to Black (via a Setter), and if it's False, the background is set to White.

Now I have a DispatcherTimer that runs at 100ms intervals that invokes a method on the CellCollection object. The method evaluates the state of the array, and changes the value of some of its elements' State property. As the value of the State property changes, the changes are reflected in the GUI as expected.

The only problem with this, is that it is terribly slow.

So the CellCollection method called by the dispatcher works in 2 parts: first it calculates what the new state of the cell array should be and stores the results in a 100x100 bool array. And second it iterates through the Cell array and updates the State property of its elements based on the values in the bool array. I printed some timestamps to the console, and it seem that calculating the bool array takes around 10 milliseconds, so I do not believe this is a problem with my algorithm being inefficient, but rather I'm speculating that the slowness is due to the cells all updating almost simultaneously (triggering property change events, and in turn triggering data triggers which change the Fill value of the corresponding Rectangle).

I'm new to C# and WPF, so I'm not entirely sure how to make this faster. I've been told that one can use the Dispatcher to greatly improve performance, but I'm unsure of how to do so. I'm also aware of a BackgroundWorker class, but am not entirely sure how to use it in this case.

Originally I was binding the State property of the Cell to the Fill property of the Rectangle and using a ValueConverter to convert from a bool to a color. Somebody suggested that DataTriggers might be faster, which is what I'm currently using, but I haven't really noticed any performance improvements. Someone else also suggested that I should use RectangleGeometry and Path objects instead of a Rectangle object as it might improve graphic performance, but am not sure if this is accurate, and haven't had much luck implementing this successfully.

Anyway, what can I do to improve my application's performance?

Comment: I'm skeptical that any suggestion is going to make a significant improvement in speed. Perhaps you should make another question about what you're trying to accomplish and the best way to go about it. You may find that drawing the controls yourself is a better option.

Comment: Does the order in which the cells update matter? If not you can try updating the cell contents within BackgroundWorker (one BackgroundWorker per cell)

Comment: The simplest improvement, if it applies, is to ensure you only raise the PropertyChanged event when the Cell.State property actually changes (use a "if (value != state)..." clause).

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you only change cells that actually *change* value. If something stays the same, don't set the properties background field and don't signal NotifyChanged.

This will most likely not help. So you will need another approach. You didn't mention any input through this wpf elements. So I assume they are for display only. Updating 10K elements because it's easier to handle is well... easier to handle, but incredibly slow. What you really want is a single element showing a picture of 100 x 100 cells. Try to draw that picture into a bitmap in your code first and then make the bitmap appear on screen by using an Image control and binding to a Bitmap. While you draw, the Bitmap is the old one, once you are done producing the bitmpa in the background, you can set this new Bitmap.

You could handle the drawing of the bitmap in a background thread, but my guess is that it will be way to fast to make sense.